# How can I embed youtube videos using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, drupal, youtube, integration

I am using drupal 6.22 and i want to show my youtube image video with title, posted date and views.

I was looking for a module but i think it is better create a block with json. The problem is drupal jquery older than my script and everything explode.

**Result:**
Image 1
Title = Teo Unified 2010
Jul 9 2010 | 264 views

Image 2
Title = Teo Communications 2010
Jul 9 2010 | 264 views

Image 3
Title = Unified free
Jul 9 2010 | 264 views

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $.getJSON(

    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=5&orderby=published",
    {
        author:"MrTeotech",
        alt:"json",
    },
    function(data) {



    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {

    var updated = item.updated;
    var title = item.title['$t'];

    var url = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
    var link = item['link'][0]['href'];
    var thumb = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
    var numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];

    var month=new Array(12);
    month[0]="Jan";
    month[1]="Feb";
    month[2]="Mar";
    month[3]="Apr";
    month[4]="May";
    month[5]="Jun";
    month[6]="Jul";
    month[7]="Aug";
    month[8]="Sep";
    month[9]="Oct";
    month[10]="Nov";
    month[11]="Dec";

    var date = new Date(item['published']['$t']);
    var date = month[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + " " + date.getFullYear();

    $("#output").append("<div><div class=\"izq\"><a target=\"new\" href=\""+link+"\"><img src=\""+thumb+"\" height=\"80px\"/></a></div><div class=\"der\"><a target=\"new\" href=\""+link+"\">"+title+"</a><br/><br/>"+date + " | "+ numViews+" views" + "</div></div>");
    }); 
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should edit to give more details about "The problem is drupal jquery older than my script and everything explode."

Comment: Well for one thing, it seems like you have jQuery included twice in your page and is probably conflicting.  How are you using the jquery_update module?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Youtube videos with JQuery using the Flash plugin. Here's the syntax for embedding a Youtube video. You can specify the width and height.

```
<p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/rFY1AF4r3Ts">My great YouTube video</a></p>
```

http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/